# Google Cloud Endpoints - Make model fields required

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, json-deserialization

Is there a native way with Google Cloud Endpoints to mark fields in your model as required, so that during deserialization an error is thrown if a value is not given for that field in the request's JSON body?

For example if you have the following class, you could have some kind of annotation.

```
public class MyModel {

    private String optionalString;
    private String requiredString;

    public String getOptionalString() {
        return optionalString;
    }

    public String setOptionalString() {
        return optionalString;
    }

    public String getRequiredString() {
        return optionalString;
    }

    @ApiSerializationProperty(required = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE) 
    public String setRequiredString() {
        return optionalString;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to get endpoints to enforce that (required fields) for you.

Comment: What about the `@named` annotation?

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes That's for path and query params.